# How to set Page Scaling option in Apache PDfBox

Tags: pdfbox

In my app, I am using Apache PDFBox to render PDF file and to silent print that fine.

PDFBox works fine for rendering the PFD but I am facing issue  **scaling** comes to the picture.
Here I want to set Page scaling before printing the PDF.

In acrobat reader's print popup, there are four options for printing the PDF.
  1> Fit
  2> Actual Size
  3> Shrink over sized pages
  4> Custom Scale

Here I want to set page scaling to Actual Size. How can I do it using Apache POI ??

Comment: i would like to suggest you iText API instead of this...it have better solutions available on net..

Comment: @HardikBhalani unfortunally, it is not free

Comment: Are you talking about its solutions of iText than you might be right(dont know),otherwise iText is open source library for PDF in java

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and I felt like it was way too difficult to do this one simple thing. Even though it's not ideal, I eventually settled for the following - not even using the PDFBox printing.

The following code converts the pages to images one at a time and uses java2d to resize and print them out.

```
PDDocument pdfdoc = PDDocument.load(pdfPane.pdfFile);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final List<PDPage> pdfPages = pdfdoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pjob.setJobName(pdfPane.pdfFile.getName());
pjob.setPrintable(new Printable()
{
  @Override
  public int print( Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page ) throws PrinterException
  {
    if (page > pdfPages.size())
      return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    try
    {
      g.drawImage(pdfPages.get(page).convertToImage()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableX()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableY()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableWidth()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableHeight()
                ,null);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      LoggerUtil.error(e);
    }
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
  }
});
pjob.print();
pdfdoc.close();
```