# PDFBox create oversized pages

Tags: java, pdfbox

when I open my PDF created by PDFBOX with PAGE_SIZE_A4, in Adobe to print. It says that it will be "Shrink oversized pages" to 96%. Even if decrease the page size by myself it shows "Shrink oversized pages" to 100%.

I know it is may a duplicate to: [How to set Page Scaling option in Apache PDfBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437622/how-to-set-page-scaling-option-in-apache-pdfbox). But this is already 2 years ago.

Usign: latest pdfbox 1.8.9

My example code:

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4); //  new PDPage(595.27563f, 841.8898);
document.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
/* With or without content */
cs.close();
document.save(pdfFile);
document.close();
```

- The workaround with images is not an option.
- iText is not an option.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually Adobe print dialogs usually propose shrinking even though the paper size would fit. It happens for all printers that can not print on the whole paper size but have some unprintable margin. Adobe in such cases purposes shrinking to the area the printer can print on.

Comment: Please compare whether the effect appears with a PDF page generated by a commercial product.